# I can't style a react-router-dom Link using Glamorous

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, styled-components, glamorous

The standard way of applying styling to a third party component does not work for react-router-dom Links.

```
export const PurchaseFooterItemLink = glamorous(Link)({...})
```

[Styling makes NavLink 'unclickable' in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266433/styling-makes-navlink-unclickable-in-react/47032147#comment95231207_47032147)

I have the following code where all the components except Link are styled and it has to be styled.

```
  <PurchaseFooterListItem key={6}>
     <Link to={{pathname:'/purchase/startDate', state:{purchase: purchase }}}>
          <PurchaseFooterItemIcon src='/icons/calendar.png'></PurchaseFooterItemIcon>
          <PurchaseFooterItemText>{purchase.startDate? purchase.startDate.toLocaleDateString():''}</PurchaseFooterItemText>
      </Link>
  </PurchaseFooterListItem>
```

When I add the following to my style file

```
import {Link as ReactRouterLink} from 'react-router-dom'
export const PurchaseFooterItemLink = glamorous(ReactRouterLink)({textDecoration:'none', color: 'RGB(245,245,245)'});
```

and then import it and replace Link with it...

```
<PurchaseFooterItemLink to={{pathname:'/purchase/startDate', state:{purchase: purchase }}}>
```

...Typescript tells me that neither "to" nor "state" are properties that exist so it is not recognising it as a react router Link.  It gives the type for PurchaseFooterItemLink as

```
GlamorousComponent<object & {}, object>
```

I've tried the alternative syntax (https://github.com/paypal/glamorous/issues/145) of

```
import withStyle from 'react'
export const PurchaseFooterItemLink = ReactRouterLink.withStyle({textDecoration:'none', color: 'RGB(245,245,245)'});
```

but that doesn't work either - it says withStyle is never used.  So no idea what to try really.

Similar issues to third party components in general - [Can't style third party components using Glamorous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54216560/cant-style-third-party-components-using-glamorous)

Edit: the Typescript error message is:

```
[ts] Property 'to' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & 
IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<object & ExtraGlamorousProps, any, any>> 
& Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<object & 
ExtraGlamorousProps>
```

When you hover over PurchaseFooterItemLink it show the type as follows, to me the issue is the type is shown as object not as Link:

```
const PurchaseFooterItemLink: GlamorousComponent<object & {}, object>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My latest edit to the question...

```
When you hover over PurchaseFooterItemLink it show the type as follows, to me the 
issue is the type is shown as object not as Link:

const PurchaseFooterItemLink: GlamorousComponent<object & {}, object>
```

...led me to the answer...which is forcing the type to be correct in the style definition...

```
export const PurchaseFooterItemLink: GlamorousComponent<ReactRouterLink & {}, 
ReactRouterLink> = glamorous(ReactRouterLink)({textDecoration:'none', color: 
'RGB(245,245,245)'});
```

Not sure why glamorous is not capable of doing that given it already has the exact type but now it is an actual Link, and Link properties can be added to it.

Answer (score 2):

you may want to check [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/6v950z9vrn?from-embed) where `NavLink` are styled with glamorous, but `Link` can be styled as well. Click works.

Just check your code corresponds to the one in the example. (check versions, etc.)

Comment: That's exactly the syntax I mentioned I was using in my question.  I will check my version of glamorous though, perhaps it's a bug that has been resolved

Comment: I upgraded my glamorous slightly to version 5.0.0, while glamor was already on the latest version.  No change.  Neither the NavLink example nor my code works.  I looked at the versions on the NavLink example page and they are all quite old so thanks for the attempt but don't see this as an answer to the question unless someone is using very old versions.

Comment: This has got the bounty but it's not the answer, it's a link to code I had already tried to use but didn't solve the problem.  If you're using glamorous version 1.0 instead of 5.0 though, then it might help you.  I marked the actual answer, there's a fault in the way glamorous works with Typescript that needs to be overcome

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your post, don't know if it also exists in your code:

```
<PurchaseFooterItemLink to="/purchase/startDate" state:{purchase: purchase }}}>
```

It should be

```
<PurchaseFooterItemLink to={{pathname:'/purchase/startDate', state:{purchase: purchase }}}>
```

Comment: Hi, yes there was a typo but my code was fine.  It all comes down to one thing - you take the glamorous object and put it into the page and type "to" as a property and Typescript says there is no such thing, so it doesn't matter what value you enter, it jut doesn't recognise a single property of the underlying Link object

Comment: The error message might help: [ts] Property 'to' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<object & ExtraGlamorousProps, any, any>> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<object & ExtraGlamorousProps>'.